# Can I preserve files input at Meteor hot code push?

Tags: meteor

Background: I'm working on file uploading in `Meteor.js`, when I do a hot code push the client refresh their pages, but if they are during a file upload this stops.

My question: **"Is the Meteor `hot code push` a total refresh of the app?"**

- If so then I'm out of luck, since the `file` input cannot survive in a session/cookie.
  but:
- If not then how can I recieve hot code push `event`? *(is there a `Meteor.addListener` for this?)*

*(no, I dont have any code since this is a general `Meteor.js` question)*

Comment: I don't think there will be a way to make it survive, however could you make a resumable, chunked upload? So the user will notice a pause but then it should restart.

Comment: It's resumable, but would be nice not to bother the user giving the file pointer/input again. collectionfs.meteor.com

Answer (score 2):

The way hot code push works is it serializes your application state and refreshes the page, then restores the state. Unfortunately, file uploads are a little complicated. I imagine you're not actually storing the file upload progress in your app state, which means that if the page refreshes, it won't start up again all by itself and continue.

To fix this, you could first store the uploading file locally in a database and upload it from there. Keep track of how much has been uploaded, and then when the app refreshes, tell the app to continue from where it left off.

Obviously this is a non-trivial problem. Personally I would probably consider this an edge case and ask the user to re-upload the file rather than investing all the time needed into engineering a solution. Unless your app use case consists entirely of uploading files, at which point you have a challenge on your hands :-)

Comment: Well, actually its resumable, the complicated part is preserving the actual file pointer - had no luck putting the file object in session variable. Thought about using local storage, but what is user uploads eg. 820Mb? If to use the local storage i would save the last part of the file hoping that connection would last long enough. it's collectionfs.meteor.com

Comment: Since the user gave the site permission to access the file it would be nice if the browser could remember that the next time. future talk.